# wordpress - identfy category id from post then if statement

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Sorry im a beginner. im trying to write an if statement based on the category id of the post on a wordpress blog.

here is my code so you get an idea

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>    
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="panel <?php

if (in_category(1) ){
    echo "panel-green";
    }
if (in_category(2) ) {
    echo "panel-primary";
    }
if (in_category(3) ) {
    echo "panel-yellow";
    }
if (in_category(4) ) {
    echo "panel-success";
    }
if (in_category(5)){
    echo "panel-info";
    }
if (in_category(6) ){
    echo "panel-red";
    }
?>">

        <div class="panel-heading">
```

so the idea is that you have different panel colours relating to the category, but i cant get it right, its picking up the category's but in the wrong order

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: When you say wrong order, what are you referring to? Multiple `panel-*` tags appear in the class?

Comment: Sorry no, it seems it inserts the "panel-'colour'" but the colours dont relate to the above query. Category 1 seems to be missed, then category 2 would be "panel-green" (which should be panel-primary) and that is repeated

Answer (score 0):

This is simple ... suppose you have `post_id` in a variable `$post_id` then you will need to run this query to get category_id(term_id) of that particular post

```
$myval = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `term_taxonomy_id` FROM 
`wp_term_relationships` WHERE `object_id` = '$post_id'", ARRAY_A);
```

then you can directly get your term_id using `$myval[0]['term_taxonomy_id']`